# The Gaussian and mean curvature of an implicit surface

Tags: differential-geometry, determinant, curvature

I am trying to understand how the Gaussian Curvature and Mean Curvature for implicit surfaces are derived.
\begin{align*}
K&= -\,\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
F_{xx}&F_{xy}&F_{xz}&F_{x}\\
F_{yx}&F_{yy}&F_{yz}&F_{y}\\
F_{zx}&F_{zy}&F_{zz}&F_{z}\\
F_{x}&F_{y}&F_{z}&0\\
\end{vmatrix}}{\left({F_x}^2+{F_y}^2+{F_z}^2\right)^2}\\
\\
H&= \frac{\begin{vmatrix}
F_{xx}&F_{xy}&F_{x}\\
F_{yx}&F_{yy}&F_{y}\\
F_{x}&F_{y}&0\\
\end{vmatrix}+
\begin{vmatrix}
F_{yy}&F_{yz}&F_{y}\\
F_{zy}&F_{zz}&F_{z}\\
F_{y}&F_{z}&0\\
\end{vmatrix}+
\begin{vmatrix}
F_{xx}&F_{xz}&F_{x}\\
F_{zx}&F_{zz}&F_{z}\\
F_{x}&F_{z}&0\\
\end{vmatrix}}{{\overset{\,}{\large{2}}}\,\sqrt{\left({F_x}^2+{F_y}^2+{F_z}^2\right)^3}}
\end{align*}
These surfaces arise from equalities such as $F(x,y,z)=0$.

How are they derived? Why can they all be written in the form of determinants?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#Alternative_formulas

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature#Implicit_form_of_mean_curvature

\begin{align*}
K&=\,\frac{\nabla\,\!F\operatorname{adj}\!\Big(\operatorname{Hess}F\Big)\nabla\,\!F^{\mathrm{T}}}{\quad\left|\nabla\,\!F\right|^4}= -\,\frac{\det\!\begin{pmatrix}
\operatorname{Hess}F&{\nabla\,\!F}^{\mathrm{T}}\\
\nabla\,\!F&0\\
\end{pmatrix}}{\quad\left|\nabla\,\!F\right|^4}\\
\\
H&=\,\frac{\nabla\,\!F\,\operatorname{Hess}F\,\nabla\,\!F^{\mathrm{T}}-\left|\nabla\,\!F\right|^2\operatorname{tr}\!\Big(\operatorname{Hess}F\Big)}{\quad2\left|\nabla\,\!F\right|^3}\\
\\
&=\,\frac{\operatorname{tr}\left[\operatorname{adj}\begin{pmatrix}
\operatorname{Hess}F&{\nabla\,\!F}^{\mathrm{T}}\\
\nabla\,\!F&0\\
\end{pmatrix}\right]-\det\!\Big(\operatorname{Hess}F\Big)}{\quad2\left|\nabla\,\!F\right|^3}
\end{align*}

Comment: These formulas may be useful. \begin{cases}
\begin{split}
\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\,\partial\,\!x^2}&=\dfrac{1}{{F_z}^3}
\begin{vmatrix}
F_{xx}&F_{xz}&F_{x}\\
F_{zx}&F_{zz}&F_{z}\\
F_{x}&F_{z}&0\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
\\
\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial\,\!x\partial\,\!y}&=\dfrac{1}{{F_z}^3}
\begin{vmatrix}
F_{xy}&F_{yz}&F_{y}\\
F_{zx}&F_{zz}&F_{z}\\
F_{x}&F_{z}&0\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
\\
\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\,\partial\,\!y^2}&=\dfrac{1}{{F_z}^3}
\begin{vmatrix}
F_{yy}&F_{yz}&F_{y}\\
F_{zy}&F_{zz}&F_{z}\\
F_{y}&F_{z}&0\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
\end{split}
\end{cases}